# How to resolve the MSBI dependency error Cannot load class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'?

Tags: maven, mule, msbi

I have maven based interface, I need to connect MSBI database and fetch the data into mule.

I have added the required jar sqljdbc42.jar to build path.

PFB is the MSBI connection configuration:

```
<poll doc:name="Poll">
                <schedulers:cron-scheduler expression="${msbi.poll.schedule.cdo}"/>
                <db:select config-ref="MSBI_Database_Configuration" streaming="true" fetchSize="1000" doc:name="MSBI Select Contact CDO data">
                    <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[SELECT [Cstmr_Acct_Id] AS SAP_Account_ID1
      ,[Accnt_Nm] AS CRM_Account_Name1
      ,[Accnt_Type] AS APL_Account_Attributes___Account_Type1
      ,[Cstmr_Sgmnt] AS CRM_Customer_Segment1
      ,[Trnprttn_role] AS CRM_Transportation_Role1
      ,CASE WHEN [Accnt_Stts]='A' THEN 'Active' WHEN [Accnt_Stts]='I' THEN 'Inactive' ELSE NULL END AS CRM_Account_Status1
      ,[Rgn] AS Region1
      ,[Rgn_desc] AS Region_Text1
      ,[Clster] AS Cluster1
      ,[Clster_desc] AS Cluster_Text1
      ,[Dstrct] AS District1
      ,[Dstrct_desc] AS District_Text1
      ,[Cntry] AS Country1
      ,[Cntry_desc] AS Country_Text1
      ,[Brnch] AS Branch1
      ,[Brnch_desc] AS Branch_Text1
      ,[Trrtry] AS Territory1
      ,[Trrtry_desc] AS Territory_Desc1
      ,[New_BT_Cd] AS BT_Code1
      ,[Lgcy_BT_Cd] AS Legacy_BTCode1
      ,[Last_Update_Dt] AS LAST_UPDATE_Date1
  FROM [dbo].[vw_elqa_CRM_Accnt_Sales_Hierarchy]
  WHERE
(
  CAST(Last_Update_Dt AS date) >= CAST(GETDATE() AS date) OR 
  CAST(Last_Update_Dt AS date) >= CAST(#[server.systemProperties['mule.env']=='dev'?server.systemProperties['msbi.debug.csr.query.filterDate']:'2100-01-01'] AS date)
) AND Cstmr_Acct_Id IS NOT NULL]]></db:parameterized-query>
                </db:select>
            </poll>
```

When i run the interface it is deployed successfully but while triggering the MSBI throwing below error

```
ERROR 2017-10-30 20:58:26,792 [nol-integration-v1.3-polling://MSBItoEloquaContactCDODataUpdate/541182371_Worker-1] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.ConnectionCreationException: Error trying to load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver : Cannot load class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver' (java.sql.SQLException)
Element               : /MSBI_Database_Configuration @ app:bulk-integration.xml:26 (Generic Database Configuration)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.sql.SQLException: Error trying to load driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver : Cannot load class 'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver'
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:184)
    at org.enhydra.jdbc.standard.StandardDataSource.getConnection(StandardDataSource.java:144)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.SimpleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SimpleConnectionFactory.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.create(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:23)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createDataSourceConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.createConnection(TransactionalDbConnectionFactory.java:53)
    at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:72)
    at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:165)
    at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver$1.process(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:149)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.pollWith(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:148)
    at org.mule.transport.polling.MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.poll(MessageProcessorPollingMessageReceiver.java:139)
    at org.mule.transport.AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.performPoll(AbstractPollingMessageReceiver.java:216)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.poll(PollingReceiverWorker.java:84)
    at org.mule.transport.PollingReceiverWorker.run(PollingReceiverWorker.java:48)
    at org.mule.modules.schedulers.cron.CronJob.execute(CronJob.java:33)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
```

Getting the below error after adding dependency

```
ERROR

********************************************************************************
Message               : Response code 500 mapped as failure.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@cb5d5af
Payload Type          : org.mule.module.db.internal.result.resultset.ResultSetIterator
Element               : /MSBItoEloquaContactCDODataUpdate/input/0/0/EloquaLookupContactsCDOBulk/subprocessors/1/EloquaLookupFields/subprocessors/0/0/1/2 @ nol-integration-v1:bulk-integration.xml:92 (Eloqua Get CDO fields)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="Eloqua_Bulk_API" path="/customObjects/{customObjectId}/fields" method="GET" doc:name="Eloqua Get CDO fields">
                        <http:request-builder>
                        <http:uri-param paramName="customObjectId" value="#[flowVars.cdo.id]"></http:uri-param>
                        </http:request-builder>
                        </http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.module.http.internal.request.ResponseValidatorException: Response code 500 mapped as failure.
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.SuccessStatusCodeValidator.validate(SuccessStatusCodeValidator.java:37)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.validateResponse(DefaultHttpRequester.java:413)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:401)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:221)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
```

Comment: ,Please accept the answer if the solution works for you,others visiting this page for similar issue could get benefit.:)

Answer (score 2):

It seems sqljdbc4.jar is not found at runtime.

If you are using Maven build(pom.xml)

Add the dependency to the pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
    <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Note :Just for information-**

If any jar is not in Maven repo you are referring in your pom.xml , *you need to add it yourself to your local repository/company repository*.

**To add to your local repository**,

1.Please check if you are having correct version of driver jar.

2.Execute below to add it to local Maven repository

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<jar_name>.jar -DgroupId=<group_id_of_jar> -DartifactId=<artifact_id_of_jar> -Dversion=<version_of_jar> -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: There is no need to add it to the local Maven repo as this jar is available on the Maven central repo ;)

Comment: @PierreB. Thanks for pointing out.Update the answer.I was under impression that the jar is not in maven central,but "http://clojars.org/repo/"

Comment: Hi Mahesh, Thanks for update. dependencies error got resolved and now getting updated error.

Comment: @Thiru Can we see the  flow xml,may be "Eloqua_Bulk_API",how it  is configured.May be http connector is not being receiving expected response from the the URL you have configured.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Mulesoft, and using the answer above and @Mahesh_Loya's comment, I was able to get this working.

1. Add dependency to pom.xml, just before closing `</dependencies>` tag:

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
       <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
       <version>4.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Add the Clojars repo to pom.xml, just before closing `</repositories>` tag

   ```
   <repository>
       <id>Clojars</id>
       <name>Clojars</name>
       <url>http://clojars.org/repo/</url>
       <layout>default</layout>
   </repository>
   ```

Save pom.xml and rerun Maven, and all should be working. Happy times.